# The best way to update a millions lines in Java Batch

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I devloppe a batch with juste main method in legacy project with : java 7, hibernate and Spring using mysql database.

In this batch I want to update a several lines in a table that have more than 50 millions lines.
When I start the batch each day I have to update at least 10000 lines.

So, what is the best way to update the line without lock the table in mysql ?

Juste do one query like this :

```
update table items set is_achive = true where id in (id1,id2,id3....id10000)
```

Or use a for loop like this :

```
for(item p : ItemsList){
   update table item  set is_achive = true where id = p.id
}
```

Comment: Hibernate will batch updates for you but you might run into other issues (e.g. memory usage), better try first whichever method is easier to write and sort out the problems as you find them

Comment: Don't forget to start a transaction, if the update has to be atomic. Else you might end up with a partial update if there's some exception or error in the middle of the run.

Answer (score 1):

This depends how you determine the list of rows that need updating. If you query the database to determine the list, it's probably best just to use a DML statement like:

```
UPDATE Item i SET i.achive = true WHERE ...
```

If your concern is locking i.e. the amount of time rows are locked, you can use batching by using a cursor e.g. some id of the data source.

```
SELECT id FROM ... WHERE id >= :start AND ...
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 100 -- use a batch size that suites your needs
LIMIT 1 -- use a batch size that suites your needs
```

The limit and for update can be implemented by using a query

```
Integer end = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT id FROM ... WHERE id >= :start AND ... ORDER BY id")
    .setParameter("start", previousEnd)
    .setFirstResult(100) // batch size
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .getResultList().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Then do a query like this

```
UPDATE Item i SET i.achive = true WHERE i.id BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

or if the end is null i.e. the last batch use

```
UPDATE Item i SET i.achive = true WHERE i.id >= :start
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hibernate Criteria builder:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // create update
    CriteriaUpdate<Order> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Order.class);

    // set the root class
    Root e = update.from(Order.class);

    // set update and where clause
    update.set("amount", newAmount);
    update.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(e.get("amount"), oldAmount));

    // perform update
    this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
```

https://thorben-janssen.com/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/

Answer (score 0):

It is best to try to get to the root if it like Chris B suggested, but if it's something you can't do, then you might also consider leveraging Spring JDBC Batch Update Operations as documented here. These have existed for some time, so find whichever documentation is appropriate for the version you're using.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s04.html